# Sandbox ride request api internal server error

Tags: python, uber-api

```
r = requests.post(url = 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests',data=json_string,headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"})
```

The above curl sandbox request some time works and some times it returns

> {'code': 'internal_server_error', 'message': 'We have experienced a
>   problem.'}

What is causing the issue?

Comment: Initially it's worked , But when i executed continuously some time after comes  internal_server_error

Comment: Uber developer console-trip simulator driver and user option also not showing when this error comes in API, Plain map only showing in trip simulator screen, No other option displaying when this error comes.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is sandbox - and sometimes server is not available to process your request based on the load performance and so many other things. So if this is working most of the times - and you are getting code': 'internal_server_error' probably with error code 500 - there is nothing we can do help you-you just need to try the same endpoint request again after a while. I can check our logs as well to make sure there is nothing unusual - I will need your developer dashboard application name for this.